# Trying to grab a innerhtml from within a innerhtml

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So i've recently ran into issues with trying to move specific pieces of a `<p>` `</p>` called result.  as such i thought hey! wouldn't be easier to break each part inside of result down into another `<p>`!? well it works lol however trying to grab that inner `<p>` that in this cause we'll call vault is being difficult.  I've tried several methods but cant seem to grab it's value from outside in a document.getElementByID....here's the code below for the html.

```
 document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = Monster + "<p id='vault'> || HP: " + HP + "</p> || Defense: " + Def + " || Attack: " + ATK + " || Can it Dodge/Block: " + DB + " || Can it retaliate: " + RET + " || Initative: " + INT + " || Exp: " + MEXP + "  <input type='submit' class='new' onclick='Combat(" + loop + ")' value='FIGHT!'></input>" + "<br><br>" + A;
                            }
```

then the script that eventually calls it

```
            function Combat(id){

                document.getElementById("vault").innerHTML = id;
                document.getElementById("C").value = id
}
```

So what i'm trying is change id "C" to ID"VAULT"  inside of id ("result").
any ideas on why i can't grab vault?

Comment: So you want the ID of vault?

Comment: in your example there is no element with an ID of "C". Also, what would be the value the `id` variable in your example?

Comment: what value you get in variable `loop ` ?

Comment: yes i want the value of "vault -sam monroe.

Comment: id changes randomly throughout the entire thing that's why i need something to grab it
loop is the number of times in SettA so say they want 5 monsters then
loop = 5

Comment: `document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = Monster + "<p id='vault'>...` etc is called from within a loop, judging by your other snippets. Therefore it's likely it's creating multiple elements with an `id` of `vault`. That's invalid HTML - ids must be unique. If you want to give multiple elements a common identifier then use a CSS class. I suspect this maybe causing you problems when you try to select the vault element later in your code. `document.getElementById("vault")` will always select the first element in the page with that ID. All others will be ignored (they're not valid)

Comment: hmmm i should add the id into there....give me one sec i'll put loop in that so it gives the vault id loop number at the end...one sec

Answer (score 0):

What you want would be easier with [Object-oriented JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript).

Usually when coding JavaScript you want to be as independent of the DOM (HTML) as possible.

Consider the following example:

```js
/**
 * Monster
 */
var Monster = (function() {
  function Monster(HP, DEF, ATK, DB, RET, INT, MEXP) {
      if (HP === void 0) {
        HP = 100;
      }
      if (DEF === void 0) {
        DEF = 10;
      }
      if (ATK === void 0) {
        ATK = 100;
      }
      if (DB === void 0) {
        DB = 10;
      }
      if (RET === void 0) {
        RET = true;
      }
      if (INT === void 0) {
        INT = 100;
      }
      if (MEXP === void 0) {
        MEXP = 100;
      }
      this.HP = HP;
      this.DEF = DEF;
      this.ATK = ATK;
      this.DB = DB;
      this.RET = RET;
      this.INT = INT;
      this.MEXP = MEXP;
    }
    /**
     * getHTML
     */
  Monster.prototype.getHTML = function() {
    return "HP: " + this.HP + " || Defense: " + this.DEF + " || Attack: " + this.ATK + " || Can it Dodge/Block: " + this.DB + " || Can it retaliate: " + this.RET + " || Initative: " + this.INT + " || Exp: " + this.MEXP;
  };
  /**
   * attacked
   */
  Monster.prototype.attacked = function(damage) {
    if (damage === void 0) {
      damage = 0;
    }
    //check defences
    if (damage > this.DEF + this.DB) {
      //take damage
      this.HP -= (damage - this.DEF + this.DB);
    }
    if (this.HP < 0) {
      //Return true if it slew the monster
      return true;
    } else {
      //Return false if the monster survived
      return false;
    }
  };
  return Monster;
}());
/**
 * Area
 */
var Area = (function() {
  function Area(name) {
      if (name === void 0) {
        name = "Vault";
      }
      this.name = name;
      this.monsters = [];
    }
    /**
     * addMonster
     */
  Area.prototype.addMonster = function(monster) {
    this.monsters.push(monster);
    return this;
  };
  /**
   * attackVault
   */
  Area.prototype.assault = function(damage) {
    if (damage === void 0) {
      damage = 0;
    }
    //If no monster
    if (this.monsters.length < 1) {
      alert("You have cleared this vault");
      return true;
    } else {
      //If monsters exists, attack the first
      var monsterKilled = this.monsters[0].attacked(damage);
      //If the monster was killed
      if (monsterKilled) {
        //remove monster
        this.monsters.splice(0, 1);
        //Alert the player
        alert("Well done hero!\nOnly " + (this.monsters.length) + " remaining!");
      }
    }
    //Return maybe monsters left?
    return this.monsters.length < 1;
  };
  return Area;
}());
////GRAP HTML ELEMENT
var output = document.getElementById("current-monster");
////RUNNING YOUR GAME
//Build and populate world
var vault = new Area();
vault
  .addMonster(new Monster())
  .addMonster(new Monster());
//INTERACTION
alert("Start");
//Hit the vault till it is empty
while (vault.assault(45) != true) {
  output.innerHTML = vault.monsters[0].getHTML();
  alert("Attack!");
}
output.innerHTML = "Victory!";
```

```html
<h1 id="title">Monster Game!</h1>

<h2 id="current-monster"></h2>
```

See how i can easily access the data though JavaScript?

When coding a JavaScript game, it makes sense to keep important data and structures in your JavaScript.

Comment: ok....however here's the problem....its not a javascript name it's a html generator...ummm for example everything is randomized...let me show you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Ok so i added the bit - ADyson suggested...
                        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = Monster + "<p id='vault(" + loop + ")'> || HP: " + HP + "</p>" + " || Defense: " + Def + " || Attack: " + ATK + " || Can it Dodge/Block: " + DB + " || Can it retaliate: " + RET + " || Initative: " + INT + " || Exp: " + MEXP + "  <input type='submit' class='new' onclick='Combat(" + loop + ")' value='FIGHT!'></input>" + "<br><br>" + A;
                        }
                }
        }
        function Chest(id){
            window.open('LootGen.html', '_blank');
        }
        function Combat(id){

            var id = document.getElementById("vault" + id).innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("C").value = id;

            submit();
        }
```

However now when i run it on the " ).innerHTML;" i'm getting a

> MonsterGen.html:426 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'innerHTML' of nullCombat @ MonsterGen.html:426onclick @
>   MonsterGen.html:1

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found out exactly was was going wrong; it was the naming convention in the `<P>`.
Originally it was `id='vault(" + loop + ")'`...  this would make it `vault(1)` etc.... however the getElement was getting it by this call `("vault" + id)` so it would call `vault1`....thus two separate id's entirely....that's why it was returning null.
So I removed the () in the equation and now everything is working beautifully.